# What's the correct way to allow www-root to execute a bash script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I have a typical LAMP server setup (Ubuntu 16) with www-data:www-data setup for Apache.

I have a script that cannot be run as root but needs to run as www-data. The script recommends  running `sudo -u www-root -i -- <command>` but when I do this I get the error:

`This account is currently not available.`

How can I safely allow the www-data user to run the command, or how would I allow the current user to execute the command, if that's a better direction?

Note: the script in question is [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) which forces an --allow-root flag, but advises against it because of [security reasons](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/pull/973).

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `-i` option of sudo, that means that sudo will attempt to use the assigned login shell and environment for that user.  This is going to be a problem for the `www-data` account since that account typically is going to have a disabled shell.

```
root@srv:# getent passwd www-data
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

What you need to figure out is if you really need to the environment/shell of that user.  You don't need the `-i` option, and could just run the command without it.  This will run the command with the same type of shell as the user executing the command.

So use this instead.

```
sudo -u www-root <command>
```

If for some reason you really need to have `-i`, then you would need to actually give that account a shell (/bin/sh, /bin/bash, or your favorite).